# Changing object property by function call a thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, object, methods

How can I change the property of `av1` from calling a method within a thread? C++  In this code, compiler is normal but in runtime is generated a fatal error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<thread>

using namespace std;

class Airplane{

public:
    int vel = 0;

    Airplane *air1;

    void change_av1(){
        air1->vel = 3;
        cout << air1->vel << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
};

void myFunction();

 int main(){

    Airplane *air1=new Airplane();

        myFunction();

    return 0;
}

void myFunction(){

     Airplane *object=new Airplane();

    thread first(&Airplane::change_av1, object); // meu método dentro da thread

    first.join();
}
```

Comment: Your `main` has `Airplane *air1=new Airplane();` - but where's your `delete`? Don't do manual memory management!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is all wrong. It should look more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

class Airplane{
public:
    int vel = 0;

    void change_vel(){
        vel = 3;
        cout << vel << endl;
    }
};

void myFunction();

int main(){
    myFunction();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void myFunction(){
    Airplane *object = new Airplane;
    thread first(&Airplane::change_vel, object);
    first.join();
    delete object;
}
```

Comment: In a Librarie that I use, the objects are declared in class. And, when many things happens in a thread, I need just it, change property of some objects. Then, i can is wrong... but, i need just do it, change properties of objects by a function called inside a thread...

Comment: "_I need just it, change property of some objects._" - Do you have an idea of what can happen if you do that when other threads access the same data at the same time? [lock guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

Comment: Yes, i have idea. Thanks.  But, in my application, it's very important this aspect. maybe, i'm wrong in may way to see the situation. if someone could give other way or solution... but, the things that happens inside a thread, change aspects of one object...

Comment: "_Yes, i have idea_" - what is that idea?

Comment: "_things that happens inside a thread,_" - 
 but things *are* predictable if you're not a quantum physics programmer of sorts. You just need to deal with options. Modern OS:es helps *you* synchronize events.

Comment: This example it's for resolve my real problem. In my software, when the sounds avanced and progress, the scroll bar change your position in the track... many audios playing inside a thread. The scrol barr is one object. Is that.

Comment: Why start at this level? Try synchronizing _easy_ bits. You'll soon find out there are pitfalls even there. When you feel safe, move on to multiple audio streams.

Comment: No no , audio it's solved... super solved.. it's mixed in one áudio only, and progress of the audio modify the scroll bar...

Comment: "_In my software, when the sounds avanced and progress, the scroll bar change your position in the track... many audios playing inside a thread. The scrol barr is one object._" - Ok - if the scroll bar is the problem in this case I'm lost. Audio is super important and you nailed that. A scroll bar? I don't get it at all.

Comment: I thank everyone who answered this post, my ideas have matured. I can see that many of my conceptions may have been wrong ...  Ted Lyngmo and Remy lebeau, thanks a lot.